# What are the 3-dimensional subspaces (or quotient spaces) to which the projections are made in the given figures? (Topological Data Analysis)

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, topological-data-analysis

**EDIT: I was told by my supervisor to implement the algorithm first and then look back over the question because "*biologists' papers do not always contain the information that is necessary to reproduce their calculations*". That is to say that I will come back to this question at some point when I've had an epiphany.**

I've just started my mathematics thesis on Topological Data Analysis last week and I was given a question to resolve for next week:

"***What are the 3-dimensional subspaces to which the projections are made in figure A? Are they really subspaces or are they quotient spaces?***"

- These are the figures which are mentioned:
  [image: *A. Branching analysis*]
- A link to where the figures are from (p.10): [*Single-cell transcriptomics reveals distinct
  inflammation-induced microglia signatures*](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6216255/pdf/EMBR-19-e46171.pdf)

I am actually not sure how to proceed to resolve this question. I've skimmed over the paper and I didn't spot anything helpful, except for the figure description:

"*leads to nine distinct clusters in a two-dimensional state space inferred by generalized regression modelling*"

1. Why do they talk about a two-dimensional state space. The question mentions a three-dimensional space.
   [**j.c.**](https://mathoverflow.net/users/353/j-c): "*The three lines you call axes actually arise from the branching analysis performed by the software Monocle 2. [Relevant documentation](http://cole-trapnell-lab.github.io/monocle-release/docs/#analyzing-branches-in-single-cell-trajectories)*"
2. Using some method we project an n-dimensional space to a 2 (or 3)-dimensional space. What does he mean by "*subspaces/quotient spaces to which the projections are made*" How would I check this?
3. Do I need to find out how the branching analysis or **G**eneralized **R**egression **M**odelling works? By G.R.M. do they mean this: [Generalized linear model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model)?

**It would be great if someone could assist me with this problem, or maybe make the question more understandable.**

Comment: Do you have an advisor in your department (maybe the person who posed the question) who could give you some hints?

Comment: Yes, my supervisor who gave me the question. I just wanted to wait before asking him, just because I'm supposed to show that I'm able to work independently. I will get in touch with him, if I don't figure out more on my own or with the help of the internet.

Comment: If your advisor doesn't want you to ask him the answer, then he probably doesn't want you to ask the internet the answer.

Comment: I am not really asking the internet for the answer nor would I ask him for the answer. I'm asking for assistance of how to proceed. The PhD student I went to today told me the question wasn't exactly clear and I should ask for more details, which I did. However my supervisor is currently travelling and hasn't responded to me e-mail yet. It's always possible someone has any helpful hints, otherwise I'll just have to wait until he responds or until my next meeting.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, I got confused with the axes, just because the question talks about a 3-dimensional subspace.